# Why i got this error when i'm trying to use Reference Template variable or using $event in angular

Tags: angular

[Here is Header.component.html file[And This is the Error which i got while passing function parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OofQA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In typescript the Params should has a type.

try this:

```
GetVal(InputValue : any)
```

also for best practice it is always better to make the name of the methods and params small letter

```
getVale(inputValue :any)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ali sir. It works . I’m finding this solution  from last month. ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use type every time here if it is Html input tag
Then it is adviced to use that only
But as mentioned by Ali any would also do the trick as it takes all types under it
But try to be specific

Comment:  Thank you Nikhil sir 